# Google Invisible reCAPTCHA with PHP, no Response

Tags: php, recaptcha, invisible

Can't seem to get the Google invisible reCAPTCHA to work. This should be easy, looking to find out what I'm doing wrong. Here's my client side code:

```
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">

    var onSubmit = function(token) {
      console.log('success!');
    };

    var onloadCallback = function() {
      grecaptcha.render('submit', {
        'sitekey' : '------my site key---------',
        'callback' : onSubmit
      });
    };
</script>
</head>
```

Form:

```
<form action='/mail-script.php' target='_self' method='POST' id='econtact'>
<input class='w3-input' type='text' placeholder='Name' required name='Name'>
<input class='w3-input w3-section' type='text' placeholder='Email' required name='Email'>
<input class='w3-input w3-section' type='text' placeholder='Subject' required name='Subject'>
<input class='w3-input w3-section' type='text' placeholder='Comment' required name='Comment'>
<button class='w3-button w3-dark-blue w3-section' type='submit' name='submit'>
<i class='fa fa-paper-plane'></i> SEND MESSAGE</button></form>
<script src='https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js?onload=onloadCallback&render=explicit' async defer></script>
```

Serve side code:

```
<?php 
function checkCaptcha(){    
if(isset($_POST['g-recaptcha-response'])){
    $captcha = $_POST['g-recaptcha-response'];

    $postdata = http_build_query(
        array(
            'secret'   => '----------secret code----------',
            'response' => $captcha,
            'remoteip' => $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']
        )
    );

    $options = array('http' =>
        array(
            'method'  => 'POST',
            'header'  => 'Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
            'content' => $postdata
        )
    );

    $context = stream_context_create($options);
    $result  = json_decode(file_get_contents('https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify', false, $context));

    return $result->success;
}else{
    return false;
    }
}
  $captcha_result = checkCaptcha();

echo("the captcha result is: " . $captcha_result);
?>
```

So $captcha_result is blank. I can't get it to detect anything. I get the sense 
g-recaptcha-response isn't being passed through the form correctly, or something else is going on. Thanks for the help.

**UPDATE:** var_dump($result); = NULL

Comment: `var_dump($result)` and update your question with the output.

Comment: Returns  NULL value. Hmm..

Comment: That means `json_decode` failed, do a `var_dump` on `file_get_contents`

Comment: Warning: file_get_contents() [function.file-get-contents]: URL file-access is disabled in the server configuration in /home/content/40/8149040/html/mail-script.php on line 34

Warning: file_get_contents(https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify) [function.file-get-contents]: failed to open stream: no suitable wrapper could be found in /home/content/40/8149040/html/mail-script.php on line 34
bool(false)

Comment: Check your page's source code, there must be a value there

Comment: Updated comment... it appears a server configuration may be an issue here? I'm on a paid host, not sure about configuration options available to me.

Comment: Use CURL, [here](https://github.com/mehdibo/Codeigniter-recaptcha) is a library I made to use reCAPTCHA. It's made for CodeIgniter but you can tweak it to your needs.

Comment: The library seems like overkill? I'd like to try to find a more simple solution.

Comment: Well as I said use cURL. You can copy the part from the library I gave you and use it or make your own code, whatever suits you! also for privacy concerns _in my opinion_ don't send the IP address, it is optional.